# In a Phoenix app, where do the prepare_changes calls belong?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

When you need to update, say, a counter cache, in Ecto 1.0 you'd use callbacks.

In Ecto 1.1 you have to use Ecto.Changeset.prepare_changes/2.

Do you put prepare_changes directly in MyApp.MyModel.changeset or in MyApp.MyController.update ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from José Valim : typically in the model.

See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654844/automatic-update-of-parent-record-updated-at-field-elixir-ecto).

Note that the repo is available in the changeset at the time prepare_changes is called.